# Java 2D string or arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I had a string dataset as follows:

row 1: "abc', "def", "ghi"

row 2: "xyz"

row 3: "lmn", "opq", "rst", "uvw"

For the start I would like to loop over each row and column and output the values in a window.

I was not sure of how to do this since, each row has different number of columns.

Could someone please tell me what would be the best way to initialize this dataset in java?

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Start by saying what you want to do. From the start to the end, in English. Then move on to how you can implement it.

Comment: I am going to assume it would be a `List<List<String>>` and not just an `ArrayList`. However, the specifics depend upon a lot of other requirements.

Comment: In my main  function i would like to loop over the rows and columns using the size of each row in the for loop and output it to a window for now. I was not sure of how to initialize this since each row has a different number of columns.

Comment: Are you reading from a TXT file?

Comment: Daniel. I am not reading from a text file. It's a simple code where I would like to initialize this 2d string at the start of my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
    List<String[]> dataSet = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    dataSet.add(new String[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" });
    dataSet.add(new String[] { "xyz" });
    dataSet.add(new String[] { "lmn", "opq", "rst", "uvw" });
```

**Option 2:**

If you know the number of rows in advance, you can also do this:

```
    int numRows = 3; //if you know the number of rows in advance
    String[][] dataSet2 = new String[numRows][]; 

    dataSet2[0] = new String[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
    dataSet2[1] = new String[] { "xyz" };
    dataSet2[2] = new String[] { "lmn", "opq", "rst", "uvw" };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First you need to decide how to parse your strings, are they different 1D arrays or all in a 2D array?  You could make a 2D array length the size of the largest array and test for nulls in the shorter ones... your simple loop would look something like this:
<code>
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) { 
    for (int j=0; j< currentArray.length && currentArray[j] != NULL; j++) { 
        System.out.println(currentArray[i][j]);
    }
}
</code>
```